# Why won't my progress bar increment properly? 

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

I am trying to increment my progress bar on a broadcast recieved but the `myProgressDialog.incrementProgressBy(increment);` code has no effect from my point of view. I have tried placing the command in different places but I still can see no effect at all.

Here is what my code looks like.

```
public static final int max = 180;
public final static int increment = (1/180);

  @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ...
        i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(ITEM_CREATED);
    registerReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(ITEM_CREATED));              
        findFeeds = new Runnable(){
           @Override
           public void run() 
            {
              getFeedObjects();
            }
           };
           beginThread();
        } 

 public static Context getAppContext() {
    return context;
}

private void beginThread()
{
    switch (checkConnectionState(OffsideLiteActivity.this))
    {
        case 0:
        thread =  new Thread(null, findItems, "DoingInBackground");
        thread.start();
        myProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            myProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            myProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            myProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            myProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
            myProgressDialog.setMax(max);
            myProgressDialog.show();

        break;
        case 1:
        connectionError();
        break;
        default:
    }
}

     private BroadcastReceiver myBroadcastReceiver =
    new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            myProgressDialog.incrementProgressBy(increment);
            Log.d("RECEIVED", "Broadcast received");
        }

   };
```

The interesting part is that logcat registers the `Broadcast received` log that i placed after the `myProgressDialog.incrementProgressBy(increment);` code

logcat

```
08-03 13:56:15.109: DEBUG/RECEIVED(8666): Broadcast received
08-03 13:56:15.109: DEBUG/RECEIVED(8666): Broadcast received
08-03 13:56:15.109: DEBUG/RECEIVED(8666): Broadcast received
08-03 13:56:15.109: DEBUG/RECEIVED(8666): Broadcast received
08-03 13:56:15.109: DEBUG/RECEIVED(8666): Broadcast received
```

Like I said I have tried putting the `myProgressDialog.incrementProgressBy(increment);` command elsewhere in my code, but to no avail. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem might be this line:

```
public final static int increment = (1/180);
```

I believe that int will be truncated to 0, so you're only ever incrementing the progress dialog by 0. You probably want increment to be 1.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a broadcastreceiver to update your UI, couldn't you just use something like an obser-observable pattern, the listener would then run the UI update in the UI thread like this :

```
public void updateUIRequested( int increment )
{
   runOnUIThread( new Runnable() { myProgressDialog.incrementProgressBy(increment); } );
}//met
```

or if you want something more modern, use an AsyncTask and still run the update in the UI Thread.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a debug point right at myProgressDialog.incrementProgressBy().... what is the value of increment? My guess is that it could be 0. Or change your Log to:

```
Log.d("RECEIVED", "Broadcast received, increment by " + increment);
```